# Querying custom object's lookups' lookup

Tags: soql, query, conga, conga-composer

Goal : To parse Record data into Conga output document from a base object's lookup field to a custom object that looks

Objects:

1. SBQQ__Quote__c (Base)
2. Project_Reference__c (Custom Object attached to SBQQ__Quote__c)
3. Reference__c (Junction object)

Fields:

- Contact__c (Master-Detail)
- Project_Reference__c (Master-Detail)

```
        SBQQ__Quote__c

             |

             V

      Project_Reference__c


            and

   Reference__c (Junction)
            / \
           /   \
      Contact   Project Reference
```

**Question:** How do I reach a Contact__r.(info) from a SBQQ__Quote__c based query? For example:

```
SELECT Project_Reference__r.References__r.Contact__r.Name
FROM SBQQ__Quote__c
WHERE SBQQ__Quote__c.Id = '{pv0}'
```

Comment: Could you please clearly indicate which object is parent and which child in each relationship? Thanks!

Comment: And what field is present on each object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your data model, your SOQL will look like the following:

```sql
SELECT Contact__r.Name
FROM Reference__c
WHERE
Project_Reference__c
IN (SELECT Project_Reference__c FROM SBQQ__Quote__c WHERE Id = '{SBQQ__Quote__c_Id}')
```